# Cannot send object in post request

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

I would like to send an object from backend to the frontend in post request. I get the object on the frontend, but there are no datas in there.

This is my function on frontend (Vue 3):

```
backend2(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/enemystrongest', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify({enemyCards: this.enemysCards})})
      .then((res) => {return res})
      .then((res) => {console.log(res)})
    },
```

And this is my backend root.js (NodeJS):

```
router.post('/enemystrongest', (req, res, next) => {
    let cards = req.body;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res.send(findEnemyStrongest(cards));
});
```

Then i get this in dev tool/console:

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:5000/enemystrongest', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5000/enemystrongest"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the body, this can be done by using: `res.json()` (this returns a promise)

```
backend2(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/enemystrongest', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify({enemyCards: this.enemysCards})})
  .then((res) => {return res.json()})
  .then((json) => {console.log(json)}) // as @jub0bs said this can be shortend as .then(console.log);
},
```

Comment: I allready have this line in my backend :/

Comment: @LabodaDániel I changed my answer. It wasn't clear for me if you where talking about the front or back-end. My excuses.

Comment: And `.then((res) => {return res.json()})` and `.then((json) => {console.log(json)})` could simply be .then((res) => res.json())` and `then(console.log)`, respectively.

Comment: @jub0bs Yes, but I believe that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Now I get this error message: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @LabodaDániel Can you try using res.json() in stead of res.send in your back-end?

Comment: Yes, but it is the same error :(

Comment: Can you print out findEnemyStrongest(cards) on your back-end and send it to me? And if you use res.json you don't need to set the content-type or stringify the json ;-)

Comment: This was the problem, the findEnemyStorngest(cards) was undefined. Now it works. Thank you so much!